# Recursive PHP Star-Rating function not working

Tags: php, function, recursion, font-awesome

I am trying to write a Star-rating function in PHP to **return** the result (not just echo it).

My newer version is:

```php
function getRating($rating, $ret = '') {
    if ($rating == 0) { return $ret; }
    if ($rating < 1) {
        $ret .= '<span class="fa fa-star-half-empty"></span>';
        $rating-= 0.5;
    } else {
        $ret .= '<span class="fa fa-star"></span>';
        $rating-= 1;
    }
    getRating($rating, $ret);
}
$var = getRating(5.0);
```

This returns null. The older version just echo it but I want it to hold the rating in a variable:

```php
function getRating($rating,) {
    if ($rating == 0) { return; }
    if ($rating < 1) {
        echo '<span class="fa fa-star-half-empty"></span>';
        $rating-= 0.5;
    } else {
        echo '<span class="fa fa-star"></span>';
        $rating-= 1;
    }
    getRating($rating);
}
getRating(5.0);
```

This one shows the `<span>` with the stars. What I am doing wrong in the first function? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you mean to use `return getRating(5.0, $ret);` to return the result?

Comment: `return $ret . getRating( $rating );` sounds like it would work.

Comment: @Dave, look at the first line of the function, `if ($rating == 0) { return $ret; }`

Comment: I saw that but it isn't related to what you are asking.

Comment: Why would you implement this as a recursive function in the first place? The rating stars you want to output don’t require the HTML code to be nested in any way, they are simply elements occurring in straight succession - so _why_ go recursive?

Comment: @misorude, I think like you say, because of that succession it needs to be recursive.

Comment: No, because of that it does _not_ need to be recursive. You want to output X number of elements one after the other here, that can be done using a simple loop, and doesn’t require recursion at any point.

Comment: Meh, I guess I learned that wrong.. If it works with a loop but less lines of code it can be a recursive function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have a return value in your function, and you should call it primarily from the outside. Here is a working example: 
https://3v4l.org/t2G7F

Code:

```
function getRating($rating, $ret = '') {
    if ($rating == 0) { return $ret; }
    if ($rating < 1) {
        $ret .= '<span class="fa fa-star-half-empty"></span>';
        $rating-= 0.5;
    } else {
        $ret .= '<span class="fa fa-star"></span>';
        $rating-= 1;
    }
    return getRating($rating, $ret);
}

echo getRating(5.0);
```

Comment: It works, but the second argument is not needed. It only needs the `return` statement.

Comment: True, since $ret has a default value among the function parameters. It's just a habbit of mine. Edited answer to remove it and fix a typo.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this by using `pass by reference`

```
 function recGerRating(&$rating, &$html=null){
    if($rating == 0 ) return $html;
    if($rating < 1){
      $html .='<span class="fa fa-star-half-empty"></span>';
      $rating-= 0.5;
      return $html;
    }else{
      $html .= '<span class="fa fa-star"></span>';
      $rating-= 1;
      return recGerRating($rating, $html);
    }
  }
 $r = 5;
 echo recGerRating($r);
```

Live example : https://3v4l.org/k8RXt

Answer (score 0):

You can pass variable by link. Always returning response from function more expensive operation than passing variable by link and change it. This approach uses less memory.

```
function getRating($rating, &$ret) {
    if ($rating == 0) { return; }
    if ($rating < 1) {
        $ret .= '<span class="fa fa-star-half-empty"></span>';
        $rating-= 0.5;
    } else {
        $ret .= '<span class="fa fa-star"></span>';
        $rating-= 1;
    }
    getRating($rating, $ret);
}

$var = "";
getRating(4.5, $var);
echo $var;
```